# Is it possible to connect a samsung watch with the PWA application by bluetooth?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-mobile-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

Is it possible to connect a samsung watch with the PWA application by bluetooth?

If it's possible: How can I get the data from my watch and use it in my PWA app?